# Custom order status not working like magento predefined order status

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status, state

I created a custom order status like below.(**This is a big issue that i am simply missing some small stuff and hope to figure out with the help of a member**).

**config.xml**

```
<sales>
    <order>
        <statuses>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
          </backorders>
        </statuses>
        <states>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
            <statuses>
              <backorders default="1"/>
            </statuses>
          </backorders>
        </states>
   </order>
</sales>
```

**mysql script**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
// Required tables
$statusTable = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status');
$statusStateTable = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_state');

// Insert statuses
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $statusTable,
    array('status', 'label'),
    array(
        array(
            'status' => 'backorders', 
            'label' => 'Back Order'
        )
    )
);

// Insert states and mapping of statuses to states
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $statusStateTable,
    array('status', 'state', 'is_default'),
        array(
            array(
                'status' => 'backorders', 
                'state' => 'backorders', 
                'is_default' => 1
            )
        )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

During the back order the order status is saved to **backorders** and it will show in the **admin panel** order list.
My question is the same order is not showing in the customers my account recent orders section.

**Why this orders under status of backorders not showing in recent orders page?**

In  the admin panel if we create an invoice the order status is changed to ***Processing***, but if i create an invoice for the orders wich belongs to **backorders** are not changed to **Processing**.But if i completed the shipping for **backorders** order it will change the order status to **Completed**

What is the issue causing this?

This is how i update the order status in the observer

```
$order->setData('state', 'backorders');
$order->setStatus('backorders');
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);                 
$history->setStatus('backorders')->setData('state', 'backorders')->setIsCustomerNotified(false);               
$order->save();
```

After order saved(**with the status of backorders**) the success screen is like below.
[image]

if i update the order status like this everything is fine.

```
$order->setData('state', 'processing');
$order->setStatus('processing');
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);                 
$history->setStatus('processing')->setData('state', 'processing')->setIsCustomerNotified(false);               
$order->save();
```

After order saved(**with the status of processing**) the success screen is like below.
[image]

**I can clearly understand there were some issue with custom created status.but i cannot found out why was that.**

Comment: did you tried by changing the status only not state mean state is `new` and status is `backorder`.

Comment: i assigned the status backorders to state backorders in the installer script right?

Comment: just for testing may be it's `state` issue.

Comment: i too guessing the same, how can i overcome this?Please help me

Comment: `$order->setData('state', 'new');
$order->setStatus('backorders');
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);                 
$history->setStatus('backorders')->setData('state', 'new')->setIsCustomerNotified(false);               
$order->save();` do something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was `state` issue use default state `new` and set your status on that `backorders`

```
$order->setData('state', 'new'); $order->setStatus('backorders'); 
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false); 
$history->setStatus('backorders')->setData('state', 'new')->setIsCustomerNotified(false); 
$order->save();
```

Comment: Thank you, what did you edit on  my question,I cannot figure out

Comment: @mujas removed extra tag

Comment: thanks. yesterday question also same.Unable to get an answer for that, so i re post it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for that:

you need go to this File Path : app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/History.php

and comment of this code

```
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
```

It will be work.

Thanks !